# Find the Probability density function of a mean random variable

Tags: probability, density-function

lets say $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n}$ are simple random samples with the PDF: $f_{\theta}(y)=\theta y^{\theta - 1} \mathbb{I}(0 \le y \le 1) $
How can I find the PDF of $\bar{Y}$? is it even possible?

Comment: Exact distribution for any $n$ likely does not have a closed form pdf. Why do you need it?

Comment: I want to find $E(\frac{\bar{Y}}{1 - \bar{Y}})$ and the only way I thought of is to find the PDF of $\bar{Y}$ and then to compute by the definition

Comment: Previously asked: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/202432/119261. I guess the original problem is to check if the MOM estimator $\frac{\overline Y}{1-\overline Y}$ is unbiased for $\theta$ or not. If that is the case, then you don't need to find the exact expectation: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185959/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thanks :)