# Meaning of the notation $ \mathbb{E}_{x\sim \mu_{\text{ref}}, y\sim \mu_D(x)}[\ln y] $ in GAN framework

Tags: notation, gan

A very naive question about notations used in mathematical framework for generative adversarial network (GAN). What is precise mathematical definition of terms like

$$  \mathbb{E}_{x\sim \mu_{\text{ref}}, y\sim \mu_D(x)}[\ln y]  $$

as appearing in [wiki intro.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network#Mathematical)

In generally, if $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable on probability space $(\Omega, P)$ with density function $f_X$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, then $  \mathbb{E}[g(X)]= \int g(X) dP_X= \int g(x) f_X(x)dx $ by definition.

My question is what means purely mathematically this expected value looking like object
$  \mathbb{E}_{x\sim \mu_{\text{ref}}, y\sim \mu_D(x)}[\ln y]  $ with the bottom notation $x\sim \mu_{\text{ref}}, y\sim \mu_D(x)$ in the expression above? Is this bottom notation just an additional reminder that the expected value is formed as before $\mathbb{E}[\ln y]$ with respect to two random variables $x$ and $y$, where the former has density function $ \mu_{\text{ref}}$ and the latter $\mu_D(x)$? Right, of does it mean something different?

Note, that $\mu_D$ is valued in probability measures, therefore
$  \mathbb{E}_{x\sim \mu_{\text{ref}}, y\sim \mu_D(x)}[\ln y]  $ should probably better considered as "parameterized family of distributions". But I do not understand how this object looks to be explicitly written out?

Maybe the question is trivial, but in classical stochastics I'm a little bit familiar with I never came across such bottom notation for expected values, so seems to be nonstandard "GAN specific" terminology, therefore I would like to clarify it's precise mathematical meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not standard it's common to see the bottom notation of expectation in the expression above as discussed in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72613/subscript-notation-in-expectations).

Specifically in this part of GAN's loss function, you are essentially considering an expectation over the conditional distribution of assessment samples $\mu_D(x)$ as they vary with different $x$ drawn from the reference distribution $\mu_{\text{ref}}$. Thus you're right that it should be considered as an expectation over a parameterized family of distributions and it's a way to express the expectation over both the randomness in choosing $x$ from the real data distribution and the randomness in generating $y$ from the discriminator network. The GAN training process involves adjusting the parameters of $\mu_D(x)$ to minimize or maximize its entire loss function aimed by the generator and the discriminator, respectively.
​

Comment: ok so just to sum up: For any fix random variable $X$ with distribution function $f_X$ the expectation with bottom notation $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim f_X}(g(X)]$ and the "standard" notation for expectation $\mathbb{E}(g(X)]$ (by def $:= \int g(x)f_X(x)dx$) are the same, right? And specifically in the context on GAN formalism $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim \mu_{\text{ref}}, y\sim \mu_D(x)}[\ln y]$ means written out  $E(x):= \int \ln(y)\mu_D(x)$, so in english a function with argument $x$ where $x \in S$ is an picked element in the target

Comment: of random variable $X: \Omega \to S$ with distribution $\mu_{\text{ref}}$, right?

Comment: Yes you're right since in GAN here the r.v. $y$ is conditioned on the r.v. $x$ which follows the ref distribution, so essentially the law of total expectation applies here.